# Is it possible to make an off hand attack then ready an action?

Tags: dnd-5e, rogue, sneak-attack

A rogue can get multiple sneak attacks per round but only once per turn. Can he use his bonus action to make an off-hand attack then ready his attack action as the next turn is starting to make a main hand attack, dealing the sneak attack damage again? This is assuming that both attacks qualify as sneak attacks

For wording ('perceivable circumstance'), it's easy to simply ask to make an attack when the enemy prepares to do so too, or in tandem with an ally, so there is no problem there.

Of course there are trade-offs, you sacrifice both your reaction and bonus action, rather than simply hoping for an attack of opportunity using your main hand attack. And it also is replaced by the Sentinel feat *if* the rogue takes it, but otherwise it frees the feat up so a tank can take it to be more threatening

Comment: According to the third benefit of the feat, "When a creature within 5 feet of you makes an attack against a target other than you (and that target doesn’t have this feat)," so I assume it's so that monsters don't end up in a lose-lose situation no matter who they attack. Two people taking the feat actually weakens the person who took it first, (but of course they're stronger than from before they took that feat.). I'm mostly referring to it for the reliable AoOs

Comment: Ah, right. I see what you mean.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. To attack with Two Weapon Fighting, you need to take the Attack action, not the Ready action.

> **When you take the Attack action** and attack with a light
>   melee weapon that you’re holding in one hand, you can
>   use a bonus action to attack with a different light melee
>   weapon that you’re holding in the other hand.

The fact that you're using the Ready action to ready an attack is sadly irrelevant - if you want to use two-weapon fighting, you have to attack first.

[You could do this if you were under the effects of *Haste*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/93801/15469), using the Haste action to attack and triggering two-weapon fighting, then using your action to Ready. Of course, at that point, you wouldn't actually need two-weapon fighting anyway.