# What else can you do in the turn you ready an action?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, readied-action

Suppose that, on your turn, you ready an action to hit the enemy in front of you if he tries to hit your friend.

What else can you do in the turn you ready the action?

(I'm asking about the turn during which you decide to ready the action "hit the enemy" - not about extra things to do as part of the readied action itself, e.g. "hit the enemy and then move away".)

Can you, for example, move close to an enemy and then ready the attack if he hits your friend?

Can you move closer to an enemy, hit him with your offhand weapon (bonus action) or use some other abilities (Second Wind for fighters) and then ready the action to attack if he hits your friend?

Comment: related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/93987/is-it-possible-to-make-an-off-hand-attack-then-ready-an-action

Answer (score 15, accepted):

'Ready' is an action, so you can do everything you do normally on a turn apart from taking your action:

- Move up to your speed
- Take a bonus action (e.g. rogue's cunning action)
- Interact with an object (e.g. draw a weapon)
- Speak a short sentence
- Do other things that don't require an action (e.g. use action surge)

Note that in order to attack with your offhand weapon using Two-Weapon Fighting, you need to take the Attack action on your turn, so you cannot use it if you ready an attack to happen on someone else's turn.

Comment: Also worth noting, because Ready is just an Action, you could Ready an attack, THEN move. The Ready Action does not have to be the last action (lower case 'a') you take on your turn.