# Can you ready an action after you've already used your bonus action?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions, readied-action, bonus-action

Like say, you use the rogue's cunning action to disengage, then you ready your action to shoot at the enemy when an ally gets within 5 feet of them.

Would this work?

Comment: Have you read the rules? Is there something specific that's confusing you? Why do you think this can or can't be done?

Comment: Related: [What else can you do in the turn you ready an action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/152196/what-else-can-you-do-in-the-turn-you-ready-an-action)

Comment: Not convinced this is an appropriate dupe - we dupe based on questions not answers. That questions is 'What can you do on the same turn you ready an action?' This question is about whether the order you take those actions matters.

Comment: @Tiggerous OK, I'm convinced; this question is about order of actions vs. bonus actions, so I've reopened it. It might still be a dupe of some other question out there about the order of actions and bonus actions, but that's a different conversation...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Yes, you can use a bonus action before readying an action

In [the basic rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#BonusActions) it states:

> You choose when to take a bonus action during your turn, unless the bonus action's timing is specified, and anything that deprives you of your ability to take actions also prevents you from taking a bonus action.

So, unless the specific bonus action you are using states otherwise, then you can use it at any point on your turn, before or after your action. Examples of bonus actions that do indicate specific timings include the unarmed strike granted to Monks via the [Martial Arts](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes#MartialArts) feature, and the additional attacks granted by [Two-Weapon Fighting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#TwoWeaponFighting) or the [Crossbow Expert feat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/crossbow-expert).

The Rogue's [Cunning Action](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes#CunningAction) has no such limitation, so is fine to use before your action (whether you take the Ready action, or any other standard Action).